# Laravel Tinker is using old values from database

Tags: laravel-5

I've updated a webhook URL in my database, but when I try to spawn an event in Laravel Tinker that should post a message to a slack channel, it's using the "old" testing URL and not the new URL from the database.

Each store has a one-to-many relationship to a slack integration.

```
>>> foreach ($store->slackIntegrations as $integration) { print $integration->webhook_url; }

https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0K572A2W/B8R8MPMV2/XXXX
```

When an invite event is spawned, with the id of the store_invite a notification should be posted to the configured slack channel.

```
>>> $e = new \App\Events\InviteEvent(179605);

=> App\Events\InviteEvent {#1005
     +body: 179605,
     +socket: null,
   }

>>> event($e);

GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException with message

'Client error: `POST
https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0K572A2W/B30D7AV52/XyzXyz`
resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: No service'

/**
The above endpoint URL is invalid and no longer set in the database. 
*/
```

The event logic is as follows.

```
public function handle(InviteEvent $event)
{
    // This fetches the ids in the event body.
    $ids = $this->getIds($event);

    $store_invites = Invite::with(['store' => function ($q) {
        $q->withoutGlobalScopes();
    }])->find($ids);


    $invites_to_slack = $store_invites->filter(function ($invite) {
        return $invite->shouldSlack();
    });

    $invites_to_slack->each(function ($invite) {
        $invite->sendToSlack();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with me not having updated the same Database as the project `.env` file was referring to.